# Create base64 circle on fly

Tags: javascript

I want draw a PNG (with transparent) circle on fly and produce a base64 image, this is my code

```js
function createCircle(size, color) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    canvas.width = size;
    canvas.height = size;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(200, 200, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}

const base64 = createCircle(100, 'red');
console.log(base64);

document.getElementById('test').src = base64;
```

```html
<img width="100" height="100" id="test" style="border: 1px solid black">
```

But the image is empty...

EXPECTED RESULT

[image]

Comment: `context.arc(200, 200, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI);` should be `context.arc(size/2,size/2, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI);`. The current circle is to big for your canvas

Comment: @DarkBee ok, now the image is fulfilled with color, but not a cicle

Comment: The third argument also needs to be `size/2` to make the circle have a correct radius, the first two just set the arc's center point. See: [context.arc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc)

Comment: Yep, now works!